# React Native app running out of memory and crashing when filling a large FlatList

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-persist

On android devices (on iOS it works fine), both in release and debug modes, my app rus out of memory and crashes as I scroll down on a FlatList and a redux action adds new items fetched from an our API to the list. Here is the FlatList:

```
<FlatList
    style={{ width: '100%' }}
    ListFooterComponentStyle={{ marginBottom: 15 }}
    //ListFooterComponent={() => isLoading || (dataSynchronizing && !isSyncingHidden) ? <View style={{ paddingVertical: 2, alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 12 }} ><DotsLoader color={Colors.blue} size={10} /></View> : <View style={{ height: 0, margin: 0, padding: 0 }}></View>}
    ListEmptyComponent={() => (isLoading ? null : <DefaultText style={{ fontSize: 15, width: '100%', textAlign: 'center', color: Colors.lightgray, marginTop: 20 }}>{T.i18n.t('reports.none_found')}</DefaultText>)}
    data={dailyReportsWithPending.filter(report => !report.is_draft || (report.is_draft && report.user_id == userId)).sort((x, y) => { y.id - x.id })}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    onEndReachedThreshold={0.01}
    onEndReached={() => {
        console.log("next page", reportsPage)
        if (!dataSynchronizing)
            store.dispatch(dailyReportsActions.loadDailyReports(activeProject.id, userEmail, authenticationToken, reportsPage));
    }}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    initialNumToRender={10}
    onRefresh={onRefresh}
    refreshing={refreshing}
    windowSize={8}
    removeClippedSubviews={true}
    
/>
```

To help debug this issue I'm simply listing IDs for each item:

```
const renderItem = ( itemData ) => (<Text>{itemData.item.id}</Text>);
```

The IDs show fine on the list, but as it gets larger and larger the native heap grows and grows until the app crashes. Here is an Android Studio Profiler snapshot:

[image]

Here is the Redux action (which I use redux-persistor with) that adds the items to the list:

```
export const loadDailyReports = (projectId, email, token, page) => {
    return async dispatch => {

        dispatch(authActions.setDataSynchronizing());
        let resources = ['not-empty'];
        const response = await fetch(`${Environment.active}/api/v2/projects/${projectId}/daily_reports?page=${page}`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-User-Email': email,
                'X-User-Token': token
            }
        });

        const data = await response.json();

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(data.errors.toString());
        }

        dispatch(appendDailyReports(data.resources));
        dispatch(authActions.setDataSynchronized());
    }
};
```

**EDIT**

I've narrowed down the issue to when the fetch results are dispatched to the reducer. The results are very large JSON objects for each fetch. Investigating if redux-persist is the culprit.

Comment: 1.5gb is a lot of JSON, are you sure records aren't getting duplicated or something?

Comment: you should use pagination fetch only few record each time, 1,5gb will kill any mobile

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with redux-persist. On android it was eating an enormous amount of memory as large chunks of data were persisted. The only way I could get this to stop happening was adding a throttle of 10000 ms to my config for it.